# IIS7 MVC deploy - 404 not found on some actions

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7, deploying

Once deployed parts of my web-application stop working. Index-es on each controller do work, and one form posting via Ajax, Login works too. Other then that yields 404. I understand that nothing particular should be done in integrated mode.

I don't know how to proceed with troubleshooting.

Some info:

- App is using default app pool set to integrated mode.
- WebApp is done in net framework 3.5.
- I use default routing model.
- OS is Windows Server 2008.
- IIS 7

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

EDIT:
I determined that only actions that accept ID parameter don't work. On the contrary, when I add dummy id method in Home controller of default MVC app it works.

EDIT 2:
I found the problem. Links on few pages of the site didn't use ActionLink helper. It was harder to see because of the Ajax invoking. So, **never** hardcode links to the actions on the site, even temporary.

Comment: when you say that the index views are working, are your urls pointed directly at the index, or is it hitting the default mapping? I.e., /mycontroller/index vs. /mycontroller

Comment: Default mapping, but it works if I append /Index too.

Comment: Is your target server IIS 6 or 7?

Comment: 7
see more details above

Comment: can you post the contents of the web.config inside your views folder?

Comment: You should post your last edit (EDIT 2) as the answer.  Looks like this question is unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this link for details on deploying MVC application with IIS 7 integrated mode.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs